# Отдача статики с помощью NGINX по специфическому адресу

Tags: веб-программирование, nginx

Есть адрес:

> /img/t1/123456/f.jpg/thumb_img

Конфиг для статики NGINX выглядит так:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)/thumb_img$ {
       root  /home/user/dev/img/;
}
```

И в логах NGINX пишет такую ошибку:

```
[error] 15228#0: *1 open() "/home/user/dev/img/img/t1/123456/f.jpg/thumb_img" 
failed (2: No such file or directory), 
client: 127.0.0.1, server: site.dev, 
request: "GET /img/t1/123456/f.jpg/thumb_img HTTP/1.1", host: "site.dev"
```

Как правильно в данном случае написать раздачу статику, чтоб по указанной выше ссылке раздавался контент лежащий по адресу */home/user/dev/img/* ?

P.S. весь конфиг целиком при котором идет переадресация на `/img/t1/123456/f.jpg` но дальше срабатывает серверный скрипт а статика сёравно не открывается.:

```
server {
      listen   *:80;
      server_name    site.dev;
      location /static/static/clip/ {
             rewrite ^/static/static/clip/(.*)$ /$1 break;
             root  /home/user/dev/clip/;
       }
       location ~ \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)/thumb_img$ {
             rewrite (.+)\.(\w+)/thumb_img$  $1.$2 permanent;
       }  
       location ~ \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)$ {
             root  /home/user/dev/img/;
       }
       location / {
               include uwsgi_params;
               uwsgi_pass unix:/var/tmp/site.sock;
               uwsgi_param   UWSGI_CHDIR     /home/user/dev;
               client_max_body_size 100m;
               proxy_set_header   Host $host;
               proxy_set_header   REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
}
```

Еще один вариант конфига при котором место где должна лежать статика получается `/home/user/dev/img/img/t1/123456/f.jpg/thumb_img`.

```
server {
      listen   *:80;.
      server_name    site.dev;
      location /static/static/clip/ {
             rewrite ^/static/static/clip/(.*)$ /$1 break;
             root  /home/user/dev/clip/;
       }
       root        /home/user/dev;
    location /img/{

        location ~ \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)/thumb_img$ {
            rewrite (.+)\.(\w+)/thumb_img$  $1.$2 permanent;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)$ {
            log_not_found off;
            expires 90d;
            gzip on;
            gzip_static on;
            gzip_http_version 1.1;
            gzip_comp_level 8;
            gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript;
         }

         return 404;
       }
       location / {
               include uwsgi_params;
               uwsgi_pass unix:/var/tmp/site.sock;
               uwsgi_param   UWSGI_CHDIR     /home/user/dev;
               client_max_body_size 100m;
               proxy_set_header   Host $host;
               proxy_set_header   REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
}
```

Comment: Вы мне можете объяснить, зачем префикс `/thumb_img`?

Comment: Так получилось что это часть наследия. Есть пару сотен тысяч документов, и штук 200 разных шаблонов с таким префиксом.

Comment: Если эта часть имени файла, в данном случае раширение, то этого не может быть. Файловые системы [ext (linux)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) и тем более [ntfs](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) не поддерживают в имени слеш `/`. Или это всё же выставленные (пребитые гвоздями) src-ки `<img src="">` в шаблоне приложения/вёрстка, которая хранится в БД?

Comment: Это не часть имени файла, в данном случае имя файла `f.jpg` а `thumb_img` говорит скриптам какой размер файла нужно брать (сохранено несколько дубликатов разного размера).

Просто раньше статика отдавалась с помощью серверного кода, и хранилась в `GridFS` а сейчас было решено просто отдавать через `NGINS`

Comment: [Попробуйте так](http://pastebin.com/CJQWCzxx). Я проверил, у меня работает. Происходит перманентный редирект на файл без этого префикса.

Comment: У меня к сожалению кардинальным образом ничего не поменялось, в логах пишет:                                                                                                      `[error] 20727#0: *1 open() "/home/user/dev/img/img/t1/123456/f.jpg/thumb_img" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: site.dev, request: "GET /img/t1/123456/f.jpg/thumb_img HTTP/1.1", host: "site.dev"`

Comment: Понятно. А кто вам подсказал `root /home/user/dev/img/;` поставить. [Пробуйте так](http://pastebin.com/HBEz6J3D).

Comment: Если снова не выйдет. Мне нужен либо весь конфиг, либо только верхняя его часть, где указаны директивы `server_name`, `root`. Именно основной `root` меня интересует.

Comment: [Этот](http://pastebin.com/HBEz6J3D)  вариант не работает примерно таким же образом как и предыдущий. Предполагалось что
`root /home/user/dev/img/;`  это будет путь к папке от корня файловой системы, где будут хранится все картинки сразу.

Comment: Вот [пример полного конфига](http://pastebin.com/g7LPiH7q) с учётом ваших особенностей со статикой, но только для php приложения.

Comment: Предполагается, что `/home/user/dev/index.php` является точкой доступа в приложение, а в папке `/home/user/dev/img/` хранится вся статика.

Comment: Привел в конце вопроса полный конфиг, у меня тогда еще один вопрос сейчас получается что при заходе по ссылке идет переадресация на `site.dev/img/t1/123456/f.jpg` но там срабатывает скрипт который генерирует 404 ошибку и все.
То есть `nginx` получается переадресует но дальше передает управление скрипту?

Comment: И второй вариант, они в принцепе идентично работают сейчас.

Comment: А данный файл `/home/user/dev/img/t1/123456/f.jpg` существует? Вот [конфиг с небольшим исправлением](http://pastebin.com/BeG81kWT). Добавил директиву `try_files $uri =404;` - если файл существует то отдаём его, если нет, то 404.

Comment: существует `/home/user/dev/img/f.jpg` а конечно `/home/user/dev/img/t1/123456/f.jpg` не существует потому что `/12345/` это динамический адрес. Я думал что все файлы в директори `/home/user/dev/img/`  без дальнейших путей.

Comment: Не понял, `/12345/` лишняя часть? Если да, то она у всех адресов присутсвует? Дело в том, что редирект должен быть на существующий файл.

Comment: Лишняя часть `/t1/123456/` но она есть во всех ссылках.

Comment: [Вот конфиг](http://pastebin.com/VdKKqGPg).

Comment: нет не отдает, в логах пишет: 
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2015] "GET /img/t1/123456/f.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 . . .

Comment: Изменённое мною правило `rewrite ([\w-]+)\.(\w+)/thumb_img$  /img/$1.$2 permanent;` указывает  `([\w-]+)` - имя файла должно содердержать любые буквенные символы, а также символ `-`. Потому мне не понятно, как попадает туда строчка со слешами `t1/123456/f`. Я проверял у себя вот такой путь `/cache/articles/0/140x119/ae22ae70e6d00093.jpg/thumb_img` он прекрасно редиректится на `/img/ae22ae70e6d00093.jpg`

Comment: попробовал с таким адресом: `/cache/articles/0/140x119/f.jpg/thumb_img`
в логах:
`127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2015] "GET /cache/articles/0/140x119/f.jpg/thumb_img HTTP/1.1" 404 63 "-" "Mozilla/5.0  . . .`

Comment: а вот с такого адреса: `/img/cache/articles/0/140x119/f.jpg/thumb_img` кажется правильно переадресует на `/img/f.jpg`

Comment: Ну у вас конечно не будет, потому как стоит `location /img/ {...}` Мой же путь содержит в начале `/cache/`.

Comment: да да то я протупил `/img/` не указал

Comment: Вот так я ещё сделал `rewrite ^.+/([\w-]+)\.(\w+)/thumb_img$  /img/$1.$2 permanent;`, попробуйте. Хотя разницы с предыдущем правилом в принципе никакой.

Comment: последний вариант переадресует с: `/img/t1/123456/f.jpg/thumb_img`
на: `/img/t1/123456/f.jpg`

Comment: Ну да, потому я и гововорю. что тоже самое  `[01/Nov/2015] "GET /img/t1/123456/f.jpg HTTP/1.1"`. Попробуйте вот такой [вариант](http://pastebin.com/HK1EnZLU) с `break` и ещё [такой](http://pastebin.com/PU0CZEYR) без `location /img/`.

Comment: Ага я кажется понял в чем разница. 
вот такая сcылка нормально работает - `/img/tt/123456/f.jpg/thumb_img` на: `/img/f.jpg`
то есть разница была тут `t1 vs tt` в этом месте цифра не позволяла правильно редиректить.

В принцепе это уже не критично, можно как нибудь отметить овет :) ?

Comment: Да, я только должен все комментарии скомпилировать в ответ :) `t1 vs tt` я умею читать/составлять regexp-паттрены, потому мне не понтяно. Мы матчим лишь правую часть, а левая часть, где `t1` должна быть любая. Я уже и изображение разместил `<img src="/img/t1/123456/f.jpg/thumb_img">` и правила в конфиге размещал. Всё у меня как положено.Может браузер или чем вы там дёргаете ваше изображение, закешировал данный путь - Ctrl+F5.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31011/discussion-on-question-by-alex10-----nginx--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location /img/ {

    location ~ \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)/thumb_img$ {
        # 301 редирект на /img/<имя_файла>.<расширение_файла>
        rewrite ([\w-]+)\.(\w+)/thumb_img$  /img/$1.$2 permanent;
    }

    location ~ \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)$ {
        log_not_found off; # не логируем, если файл со статикой не найден

        # директивы ниже по желанию (опционально)
        expires 90d; # кэшируем браузером на 90 дней
        gzip on; # активируем динамическое сжатие статики

        # указываем какой тип статики сжимать (фильтр). 
        # В данном случае, это текст, css, js
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript;

        # если рядом с файлом статики будет расположен его сжатый вариант .gz, 
        # то отдаст сразу его без сжатия (экономия ресурсов сервера).
        # Как вариант - использовать для сжатия gulp + плагин gulp-gzip
        gzip_static on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_comp_level 8;
    }

    # если файл не имеет расширение jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js, то 404
    return 404; 
}
```