# Rewrite in NGINX когда uri кончается на .php

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Всем привет. Есть сайт, в локейшене которого хочу сделать реврайт на другую страницу в случае если ссылка кончается на .php

Например если захотим сделать так
`http://www.site.com/new-inventory/getfile.php` то должны будем перейти на `http://www.site.com/this-new-rewrited-page`

Сделал так, но это не работает.

`location /new-inventory {
    rewrite .*\.php /this-new-rewrited-page;
}`

Так тоже делал:

`location ~ /new-inventory/.*\.php {
    rewrite .* /this-new-rewrited-page;
}`

Оба варианта не работают, выдаёт 404, как-будто я запрашиваю не существующий файл. Да, я запрашиваю несуществующий файл, но проверка на то существует ли файл и выдача ошибки не должна выполняться ДО того как выполнятся операции в локейшене. Подскажите что делаю не так?

`location / {
    rewrite /new-inventory/.*\.php /this-new-rewrited-page last;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
    }`

Мой локейшн /. В нём так написал.

Comment: Далее у вас по конфигу, наверно, `location / {...}` идёт. Собственно, последний и отрабатывает его. Т.е. необходимо писать проверки уже внутри этого `location`. Можно отловить раньше `location = /this-new-rewrited-page {...}` - указываем точное совпадение. В общем, слишком мало информации. Давеча, я из одного товарища вытягивал информацию, [чтобы решить его проблему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/462876/10551).

Comment: Добавил к посту как пробовал делать изменения в `/` локейшене.

Comment: Причем когда делаю rewrite без php в  конце `rewrite /new-inventory/.* /this-new-rewrited-page last;` то работает. Стоит добавить в конце `\.php` -- нет. Как-будто nginx понимает что это файл и сразу пытается его найти в этом локейшене. Нужно ему дать понять чтоб он не пытался находить этот файл.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте

```
location /new-inventory {
    try_files $uri /this-new-rewrited-page;
}
```