# Передача файла с сервера пользователю

Tags: python, flask, request

Структура примерно такая:

Пользователь жмёт кнопку "Сгенерировать отчёт", на сервере он генерируется в `zip` файле и должен быть передан обратно пользователю. Как это можно сделать на `flask` или через `request` запрос?

Серверная часть написана на [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) с использованием [flask](/questions/tagged/flask)

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете `nginx`? Если да, то мне кажется можно избавить `python` от выгрузки файла, при запросе пользователя сервер генерирует архив и записывает его в определенную директорию, с определенным именем, клиенту возвращает имя файла, а в настройках `nginx` можно прописать алиас к директории, соответсвенно по какому-нить урлу типа https://domen.com/you_folder/?file=file_name пользователь сможет получить свой файл.

Вот пример конфигурации [nginx](http://catethysis.ru/nginx-static-content/) и [еще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462876/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-nginx-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83)

Python и [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory)

Comment: а другой пользователь сможет получить этот файл?

Comment: Целесообразность этого зависит от размера архива

Comment: @Igor смотря как сделаете, можно например сгенерировать случайные буквоцифры, которые другой пользователь не сможет узнать и получить афйл

Comment: Да, используется nginx, можете написать поподробнее как добавить доступ к директории?

Comment: Абсолютно верно, другой пользователь сможет получить файл, если будет знать его имя, однако если имя файла будет типа `W123gYeb-yus67+datetime` это будет затруднительно, и да, это зависит от размера файлов, от их количества и от кол-ва пользователей

Comment: Или всё таки легче сделать на python выгрузку?

Comment: @Сергей добавил ссылок в ответ, смотрите, думаю там все понятно

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/680182/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-flask/680186#680186) про передачу файлов

Если говорить про отчёт, то тут всё слишком индивидуально, чтобы дать какую-то конкретику.

Сформируйте подробнее вопрос, касающийся отчёта и архивации данных.
Что будет содержаться в архиве, а если точнее, то какие файлы из архива должны генерироваться при помощи `Flask`.

Если генерируется csv, xls, pdf файл на основе данных из БД, и данных много, то такую задачу лучше ставить в очередь.

Comment: Формируется zip из картинок

Comment: @Сергей, у вас уже есть код, который генерирует сам zip ?
Если да, то используйте один из тех способов, что я привёл по ссылке на другой ответ.