# Передача файла с помощью flask

Tags: flask

Как передать файл с сервера пользователю при нажатии кнопки на сайте с помощью фласк? Для передачи события использую flask-socketio, ими передаю команду на создание файла. А как его выгрузить с сервера клиенту не понимаю.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/680140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то можно вот так, используя `send_from directory`

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/download/<filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory('path_to_file', filename)
```

а в шаблоне кнопку сделать, например,  так:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=filename) }}">Скачать</a>
```

[Тут](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory) подробно описано про `send_from_directory`

Если же речь идёт о картинке, или файл имеет какой-то определённый `mimetype`, то можно использовать `send_file`

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/get_image')
def get_image():
    return send_file(filename, mimetype='image/gif')
```

[Тут](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file) подробно описано про `send_file`